# I have always wondered this, is it better to do cardio prior to lifting or after lifting?

Tags: strength, diet, bodybuilding, strength-training, lifting

I constantly see on social media (i.e. TikTok and Instagram) that people insist on doing cardio before heavy lifting and others saying the complete opposite that they would rather do it after for optimal muscle growth. Which is the best way for muscle growth and a goal to get lean? I am not talking about running specifically but stairs, bike, etc. I tend to do incline treadmill at a 15 incline for 3.5 speed.

Comment: I'm no expert, but I friend of mine is a personal trainer and owns 2 gyms and is a former professional football player. He suggests that lifting weight first and then doing cardio will help your body lose weight. Cardio before hand should be used for warming up.

Comment: There are lots of prior questions in this area: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/search?q=cardio+before+weights